# It's possible to use ionic-cli 3.0.0 without typescript and angular?

Tags: ionic3, ionic-cli

I just want to use ionic livereload provided by `ionic serve`, but just using vanilla javascript without typescript or angular things. If it's possible, how can I achieve that? Until now, I only have errors like:

```
[ERROR] Error occurred while loading plugins. CLI functionality may be limited.
        Checking for CLI updates now...
[ERROR] No updates found after plugin error--please report this issue.
```

My `ionic info` returns the same error above plus:

```
global packages:

    @ionic/cli-utils : 1.0.0
    Ionic CLI        : 3.0.0

System:

    Node       : v7.10.0
    OS         : Linux 4.10
    Xcode      : not installed
    ios-deploy : not installed
    ios-sim    : not installed
```

Comment: You may be missing a plugin in your _local_ `node_modules` directory/`package.json`. That said, I would not use something as heavy as the Ionic CLI just to get live reload. Try _lite-server_  (`npm i -g lite-server`)

Comment: @AluanHaddad Thanks for your comment! I'm developing a cordova app, but I don't need the typescript and angular things provided by ionic.

Comment: The CLI is pretty rigid. It is a pain to get at the internals. You can write custom plugins that _override_ some default behavior but you will likely be fighting the toolchain most of the time. (based on very limited experience)

Comment: @AluanHaddad thanks again for your comment. For now I just downgrade ionic CLI to version 2.2.1

Comment: `"angular things"` what is angular things? . And if you mean the framework iteself then no just no you cant do that. Ionic is build ontop of angular. So it would be like taking the foundation out of a building the building will fall because there is no foundation.

Comment: @gerdi the question was about **ionic-cli 3.0.0** not about the whole framework itself and I believe that angular is optional to ionic, once that its support is provided by a plugin [https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/tree/master/packages/cli-plugin-ionic-angular](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/tree/master/packages/cli-plugin-ionic-angular). In fact, I've even been using ionic without angular or typescript for a while.

Comment: angular is not optional with ionic .. that is just not possible.I know you can run it without typescript , but not angular. I dont think i understand what you are asking because that plugin you ref is just for the command line interface  which adds angular functionality to the cli

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and I'm solved it by remove folder 'node_modules' and run command
`npm install`

Answer (score -1):

`$ npm install -g cordova
 $ npm install --save-dev --save-exact @ionic/cli-plugin-cordova@latest`

Run Both commands. It solved my same issue. If you have proxy url install that too.